# Nesting Dependency Backbone.js Views with Require.js Backbone.js Leads to View Loaded as Object Instead of Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js, requirejs

I'm using Require.js with Backbone.js and Underscore.js, and I have a nested view that is coming up as undefined when called as a dependency, but when I have the two views in the same module, they work fine. I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong. Here's an example:

child-view.js

```
define([
'jQuery',
'Underscore',
'Backbone', 
], function ($, _, Backbone) {
var ChildView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        this.render();
        },
    });
    return ChildView;
});
```

parentview.js

```
define([
'jQuery',
'Underscore',
'Backbone',
'src/views/child-view'
], function ($, _, Backbone, ChildView){
 var ParentView = Backbone.View.extend({

        initialize: function () {
            _.bindAll(this, 'render');

            this.render();
        },
       render: function () {
              child = new ChildView({});
       }
    });
    return ParentView;
});
```

I receive a "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" when trying to call the new ChildView. If I reference the ChildView outside of the Parentview but inside of parentview.js, it displays the view, but as an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just from your code, there should be no problem, I tested your code actually did not find the problem.
This is my test code，you can try it：
http://files.cnblogs.com/justinw/test_byfejustin.zip

I think it might be your “require.js” have a problem,you can replace your "require.js" with my "test_byfejustin\js\libs\require\require.js" in my code package,and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Variable names are case-sensitive.  In child-view.js you are returning "ChildView" which is undefined (you've assigned childView).